# More than 2 webcams on Windows

Tags: windows-7, webcam

Well, for the project I envisioned I have MY software and want to attach 4 webcams to the PC.  I dug deep down into development only to find out that...

Windows won't work with more than 2 webcams?!

Is there a way around that problem?

*Information about my configuration:*

- Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit)
- Relevant applications running in x86 mode
- Canyon or Prestigion 2Mpix web cam (running in 640x480 resolution at 30 FPS)

Comment: What type of web cams are you using?  Which software are you using to access those web cams?  Which edition of Windows are you using?

Comment: Actually, none of the tags indicates a 64-bit OS.  I updated your question to mention the OS (you still didn't which edition) and application architecture information.  =)

Comment: The edition can be relevant since the Home Edition is known to have some limitations that the others don't.  Whether these limitations would effect the total number of web cams connected is not clear to me (although I assume that it shouldn't be an issue), but there could be some other limitation that may be at the root of the problem you're experiencing and someone else who's familiar with your type of setup may recognize it and be able to help you more promptly (at least, this is what we hope for around here).  I'll update your question again, and then we should delete these comments.  =)

Comment: Having this additional information can be helpful to others trying to help you.

Comment: Are you asking about application development, or a certain software package? If you're asking about developing an application that integrates webcams, this post is more suited for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Each of your webcams produces 35MB/s RGB stream saturating USB2
Consequentially 2Mpx is available only in YUV mode (packaging 32 bits into 6 )

Answer (score 2):

Personally I have no issue running more than 2 cameras from a Linux box, via zoneMinder, but the Windows equivalent: iSpyConnect, states you should be able to run 4 cameras at 320 x 240, on a windows box with 2GB ram, see: http://www.ispyconnect.com/userguide.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue while working on a java image processing project. I was using windows 7 professional 64 bit. I could not capture from more than two video devices when at 640X480 resolution using OpenIMAJ java library.

I was able to add an additional camera when I reduced the resolution to 320X240. I presume this is a hardware limitation on the system as I could not find any other reason for the exception.

Do correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem with more than two webcams on Win7, even Home Edition, I'm running a few right now.  Without further information, such as an error message when running more than two webcams, I can't be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you that Win7 allows more than 2 webcams. For my college project I used 2 "security" cameras for a development I made, and both were handled as webcams in my program. They were USB cameras.

By any chance you have the factory software for each webcam installed in your pc? That may be causing conflicts.